# Extract instance variables referenced in a java method

Tags: java, javaparser

I have a class like below

```
class A{
    private var1, var2;

    public void methodA(){
        sout(var1);
    }
    public void methodB(){
        sout(var1);
        sout(var2);
    }
}
```

Here in that code snippet I have class with two instance variables **var1**, **var2** and two methods **methodA**, **methodB**. **var1** is referenced in both **methodA** and **methodB**. How can I extract this information from a java class?

Comment: Parse the source code and analyze the resulting model.

Comment: Are you asking how to parse java source code? Are you asking how to analyse a compiled class file? In any case:

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could [edit], rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: I am new at javaparsing. Can you please give some detail procedure @lexicore ? Thanks

Comment: This is way too broad.  I suggest you read up on Reflection in Java, and return if you have a specific problem implementing what you've learnt.

Comment: @TobySpeight You can't solve this with reflection, can you?

Comment: @lexicore, I missed the bit about reading the method body to see which variables were referenced (all that bold makes it hard to read).  Maybe reflection isn't quite enough on its own, then (it's a decade or two since I did Java).  The question is still too general for SO.

Comment: @PritomSahaAkash Check [JavaParser](http://javaparser.org/), it is quite easy to use. [No](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question), I will not give you the detail procedure.

Comment: @TobySpeight This is not doable with reflection. Just saying so that noone is misguided.

Comment: Thank you @lexicore and I will check JavaParser.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library: [JavaParser Core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/2.5.1)

```
    JavaAnalyzer jpa = new JavaAnalyzer(this, "A.java");

    AtomicBoolean var1IsReferencedInMethodA = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    jpa.visit((MethodDeclaration methodDeclaration) -> {
        var1IsReferencedInMethodA.setTrueWhen(methodDeclaration.getName().equals("methodA")
                && (methodDeclaration.getBody().getStmts().get(0).toString().equals("var1")));
    });

    System.out.println("var1 is referenced in methodA(): " + var1IsReferencedInMethodA);
```